# Custom DateTime in X axis in Lightningchart JS

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have X and axis like this , Its 15 seconds chart.

```
["2020-05-22 14:20:22", "173.9"]
["2020-05-22 14:20:40", "175.3"]
["2020-05-22 14:20:58", "172.4"]
```

I tried to add like below

```
for(var key in json)
{

    var xTime = stringToDate(json[key][0]);
    var yVal  =  parseFloat(json[key][1]);
    series.add({ x: timer, y: yVal})

}

function stringToDate(s)  {
  s = s.split(/[-: ]/);
  return new Date(s[0], s[1]-1, s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
}
```

But chart is rendering with weird values in x axis

[image]

Comment: @Snekw Hi , Request your assistance , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateTime axis for LightningChart JS expectes to receive the data as millisecond values. It doesn't support `Date` objects directly. So if you have times as `Date` objects then you would need to call [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method to get the time as milliseconds. This data can then be displayed by in the chart as time when using a [`AxisTickStrategies.DateTime`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/globals.html#axistickstrategies.datetime) on the axis that has the time values. If you want to have the DateTime axis tick strategy by default when adding a series to chart you can use [`defaultAxisXTickStrategy`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/interfaces/chartxyoptions.html#defaultaxisxtickstrategy) or [`defaultAxisYTickStrategy`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.0/interfaces/chartxyoptions.html#defaultaxisytickstrategy) if the time is on the Y axis.

When you are displaying the current time or close to current time you will need to use a `origin` for the values and add the times as offsets from that origin time.

```js
const dateOrigin = new Date()
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: AxisTickStrategies.DateTime(dateOrigin)
})

const series = chart.addLineSeries()
const xTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 100000000)
const yVal = 1
series.add({ x: xTime.getTime() - dateOrigin.getTime(), y: yVal})
```

See a working example below.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    AxisTickStrategies
} = lcjs

// Create a XY Chart.
const dateOrigin = new Date()
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
    defaultAxisXTickStrategy: AxisTickStrategies.DateTime(dateOrigin)
})

const series = chart.addLineSeries()
series.setCursorInterpolationEnabled(false)

const data = [
    ["2020-05-22 14:20:22", "173.9"],
    ["2020-05-22 14:20:40", "175.3"],
    ["2020-05-22 14:20:58", "172.4"]
]

function stringToDate(s)  {
  s = s.split(/[-: ]/);
  return new Date(s[0], s[1]-1, s[2], s[3], s[4], s[5]);
}

for(var key in data)
{
    var xTime = stringToDate(data[key][0]);
    var yVal  =  parseFloat(data[key][1]);
    series.add({ x: xTime.getTime() - dateOrigin.getTime(), y: yVal})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you , how do you show the date too in label while hovering on line chart... and also if there is gap between two data , there is gap in between , how to avoid it ? Example is trading hours of yesterday is 6 hours and today trading hours is 6 hours , how to seamlessly show it ?

Comment: For how to show the date in the result table, I would appreciate if you post another question for that. For the gap, I don't think we have any method to do that right now.

Comment: ok sure , I have asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066674/how-to-show-custom-label-in-line-chart-or-scatter-chart

Comment: sir any update on my two new questions ? I am checking stackoverflow daily for your answers..