# how to use Datetime Axisx in lightningchartV2.2.1?

Tags: lightningchart

I noticed the answer in [Custom DateTime in X axis in Lightningchart JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61974214/custom-datetime-in-x-axis-in-lightningchart-js/62059135#62059135), but it report error "AxisTickStrategies.DateTime is not a function" in lightningchartV2.2.1.
also, since AxisTickStrategies.DateTime is not a function, how can i  show a full date axisx label for a series using a DateTime axis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at official LCJS Interactive Examples, and search for "datetime"

For example,
https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0020-dateTimeAxis.html

This is the bare minimum required code - please refer to the examples for extended modification.

```
chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTickStrategy(
        // Use DateTime TickStrategy for this Axis
        AxisTickStrategies.DateTime,
    )
```